# Bootstrap - how to prevent columns overlapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and text, and they overlap. If I switch the column size to lg, i.e. class="col-xs-6", then the text collapses underneath. However, I would like them side by side until the browser doesn't allow, and then collapse.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
<div class="row " style="background-color:#f5fcff; border-radius:15px; margin-left:25px; margin-top:35px">
        <div class="col-xs-6"  >
          <div style="padding-top:25px">
            This table contains a list of users and how many times they've looked at a product's page (user):
          </div>
            <table class="table table-hover" style="text-align:center">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>User ID</th>
                  <th>14CBL13W</th>
                  <th>18VAEA35W</th>
                  <th>14CBL15Y</th>
                  <th>14DAEA12W</th>
                  <th>14OM6DY</th>
                  <th>...</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>234234</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>15</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>...</td>
                </tr>
                ...                  
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left:35px; padding-top:75px" >
            In this example, a new user 96887, which has looked at '14DAEA12W'. The value of '14DAEA12W' has now changed from 0 to 1. Now, which item would recommend that the user might like? If you answered '14CBL15Y' then you are correct. This is because user data is showing that there is a high amount of correlation between the two. However, this may also be part of a feedback loop - the more the item is recommended, the higher the chance that its value in this chart goes up. This chart also overlooks any item characteristic similarities, it only looks at user behavior. 
          </div>
      </div>
```

[image: Overlapping columns]

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1: Bootstrap will look nice again if you enumerate your divs as an unordered list (such as below). If you run this in jsfiddle.net it won't quite look the way you intended. If you want it to not overlap *and* stay in the same row, try to give it more space by shortening the table *or* making the list run horizontally. As for now, col-xs-1 might look good

```
<div class="row " style="background-color:#f5fcff; border-radius:15px; margin-left:25px; margin-top:35px">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li>
        <div class="col-xs-6" >
          <div style="padding-top:25px">
            This table contains a list of users and how many times they've looked at a product's page (user):
          </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <table class="table table-hover" style="text-align:center">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>User ID</th>
                  <th>14CBL13W</th>
                  <th>18VAEA35W</th>
                  <th>14CBL15Y</th>
                  <th>14DAEA12W</th>
                  <th>14OM6DY</th>
                  <th>...</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>234234</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>15</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>...</td>
                </tr>
                ...                  
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left:35px; padding-top:75px" >
            In this example, a new user 96887, which has looked at '14DAEA12W'. The value of '14DAEA12W' has now changed from 0 to 1. Now, which item would recommend that the user might like? If you answered '14CBL15Y' then you are correct. This is because user data is showing that there is a high amount of correlation between the two. However, this may also be part of a feedback loop - the more the item is recommended, the higher the chance that its value in this chart goes up. This chart also overlooks any item characteristic similarities, it only looks at user behavior. 
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>

    </ul
```

>

Comment: I tried removing any padding, border, and margin attributes, but it unfortunately did not resolve the issue.

Comment: OK don't give up hope I'm working on a new solution that requires lists but it'll make the website a lot prettier. I use it on my practice site hopefully lists make it better on yours hang tight

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `<div class="container"></div>`, put your block inside one.

Comment: I have it inside a container which starts further up on the page (out of the screenshot). To test though I put it in its own container. It unfortunately did not work.